# ':' expected error in gnuplot while plotting multi column data file

Tags: gnuplot

plotFile_bin.p

```
 1 #Chart properties
 2 set title "Cumulative binning"
 3 set terminal svg size 1200,1800
 4 set out '/ethCfmTopo/2way_delay/data/spoke-ntp/cumulative_binning.svg'
 5 set multiplot layout 10,1 title "Multiplot"
 6 set autoscale y
 7 set autoscale x
 8 set ylabel "Iterations"
 9 set xlabel "Round trip ms"
10 set style data histogram
11 set style fill solid border
12 set xtics scale 0 nomirror rotate by -45
13 plot for [COL=2:9] '/ethCfmTopo/2way_delay/data/spoke-ntp/data_binningbin.log' using COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheader, for [COL=2:9] '' using 0:COL:COL w labels title columnheader
```

---

while running the above code i am getting ':' expected error,  Searched it in many forums not getting any clue. Can anyone please help on this ?

### Error Output

```
#gnuplot plotFile_bin.p 

plot for [COL=2:9] '/ethCfmTopo/2way_delay/data/spoke-ntp/data_binningbin.log' using COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheader, for [COL=2:9] '' using 0:COL:COL w labels title columnheader
             ^
"plotFile_bin.p", line 13: ':' expected
```

### below is my datafile:

```
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
1.01-1.1        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
1.1-1.2 1       2       4       6       0       2       3       3
1.2-1.3 173     168     188     248     189     234     206     216
1.3-1.4 1529    1638    1755    1765    1816    1842    1683    1662
1.4-1.5 785     671     546     463     479     408     597     600
1.5-1.6 1       4       0       1       5       3       3       0
1.6-1.7 1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
1.7-1.8 1       1       1       2       3       0       0       1
1.8-1.9 2       0       4       1       3       3       0       3
1.9-2   0       1       0       2       4       1       0       2
2-2.3   1       1       0       0       0       0       1       0
2.3-2.6 0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0
2.6-3   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
3-4     0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
4-5     1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
5-7     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
7-10    1       1       1       1       0       0       0       1
10-16   4       13      0       9       0       7       6       11
16-21   0       0       0       2       1       0       0       1
21-31   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
>31     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Which version are you running? I get no such error on `Version 5.0 patchlevel 3`

Comment: Version 4.6.7 doesn't produce this error either.  I suspect that you are running a version older than the plot for syntax and it is not sure how to interpret the `[COL=2:9]` expression.  Can you upgrade to a newer version?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I am using gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 6. Will upgrade it.

Comment: "plot for []" loops were only introduced with gp4.4. Btw., please simplify your problem before posting it, You should've gotten down to `plot for [i=1:3] x*i`.

Answer (score 0):

Update to at least gnuplot 4.4.0. The support for iteration *(plot for [COL=2:9] ...)* was added there.